# Spacing One Picture per Page

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am currently having to attach many pictures (jpeg) to an excel document and exporting it as a pdf.  I need one picture per page.

I was using the following code, but with no avail.

```
For j = 0 To i
        Cells(2, 1).Activate
        Let pm = "Q:\Public\ACCE LINEAR\IRAD Photomics\A 350 Frame Photomics " & dat & "\" & sn & "\PHOTOMICS" & j & ".jpg"
        ws1.Pictures.Insert(pm).Select
        incr = 660 * (j + 1)
        Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop incr
    Next j
```

I activate Cell A2 so that the picture will initially be placed in the same spot every time.  I then move the picture down a certain amount as defined by the variable "incr".  At first I toyed with that number (660) until it worked and then went on to the next report.  The problem is that what works for one report doesn't work for another.

I find this surprising as I have my print area (I believe that dictates the length of a page) set to incorporate all columns.  Although each report has a unique amount of rows, they each have exactly the same amount of columns.  Therefore, the print area should be the same from sheet to sheet and each picture is exactly the same size so that number shouldn't have to change from report to report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why my previous spacing idea didn't work when the print area from sheet to sheet is exactly the same.  However, knowing the print area is the same I instead made the top left cell in each page active and inserted each picture into that cell.  This ensured that the pictures did not get cut when the excel file was exported as a PDF.

Here is the code I used.  There are a few variable that were defined earlier in the code, but you should get the idea

```
b = counter - 1
For j = 0 To b
    a = j + 1
    If i > 24 Then a = j + 2
    incr = (42 * a) - j
    Cells(incr, 1).Activate
    ws1.Pictures.Insert(MyFolder & "\" & PMArray(j)).Select
Next j
```